# Are open subschemes "nicer" than closed subschmes?

Tags: soft-question, schemes

I'm trying to learn some algebraic geometry, and of course I came across the notion of open/closed subschemes of a scheme $X$. Everytime I deal with open subschemes, I feel way more comfortable, becauce open subsets $U$ feel "better" in the sense that the induced topology is somehwat "nicer" - opens of $U$ are open in $X$, U doesn't loose properties as being irreducible and, in the Noetherian case, quasi-compactness... - and the relation of the structure sheaves $\mathcal{O}_X$ and $\mathcal{O}_U$ is of course very easy. For closed subschemes $Z$, however, I feel a bit unease because from a topological viewpoint closed subsets seem to me not as "nice" as opens - influenced of course from analytical viewpoints - and also the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_Z=i^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathscr{I})$ for an ideal $\mathscr{I}\subseteq \mathcal{O}_X$ looks more complicated. We have one sheaffification in the quotient and one sheaffification for the pull-back - my gut feeling is that it's "harder" to get a hand on this thing.

As to come to my question, I "like" open subschemes more than closed subschemes: is this valid, or are closed subschemes by far more important in applications than opens? And, of course, are closed subschmes even "harder to get a hand on" than opens, or is this just an impression at first sight?

Comment: speaking purely as a fellow AG novice, I share all your feelings. Except maybe on the topological point. Topologically, closed subschemes seem as nice as you can ask for.

Comment: Also, I hadn't heard the definition as a pullback of a quotient.  Is that the definition you're working worth?

Comment: @Timkinsella Yes, I am using the definition given in Görtz/Wedhorn. Of course, my feeling on behalf of topology may come from calculus, which is of course deceptive in algebraic geometry.

Comment: That seems like a sadistic first definition.  In Ravi Vakil's notes he defines it as a morphism of schemes such that preimages of open affines are affine, and such that on such a preimage the ring morphism is surjective. I find that a much friendlier definition.

Comment: That’s too approximate for anything resembling an answer, but I do agree that, to me, even now, open subschemes are a lot easier to use than closed subschemes. However, open subschemes are *so* easy to use, in fact, that they are almost trivial – when you show that a map is an open immersion is, in many cases, it’s just as good as if you had shown it was an isomorphism (it’s not – but open immersions preserve so many things that the difference can at times feel immaterial). Being far less trivial, closed immersions are richer and more useful. Most classical varieties are closed subschemes.